# How to read xml attribute with colon in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Given an xml, something like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="SOMETHING.Presentation.Mobile.Droid" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="1.13.0" android:versionCode="15">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application android:label="SOME_NAME" android:largeHeap="true">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="SOMETHING" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="SOMETHING.Presentation.Mobile.Droid" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'm trying to use a powershell script to rewrite it.

when I search for package like this:

```
$package = $xdoc.manifest.package
```

I get it "SOMETHING.Presentation.Mobile.Droid"

when I search for android:label (`<application android:label="SOME_NAME" android:largeHeap="true">`) I get nothing

I tried with non success:

- $xdoc.manifest.application.android:label
- $xdoc.manifest.application.android.label
- $xdoc.manifest.application.[android:label]
- $xdoc.manifest.application.[android.label]
- $xdoc.manifest.application.{android.label}
- $xdoc.manifest.application.{android:label}

How to point to attribute with "colon"?

Comment: Drop `android:` namespace and simply access `.label`

Comment: it works thak you very much!

Comment: @wOxxOm care to explain why?

Comment: welp, what to search for at least?

Comment: @4c74356b41, hmm, I guess something general like "XML namespace attribute syntax". I'm just not knowledgeable enough to point in the right direction compared to these guys [XML Default namespaces for unqualified attribute names?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3312390)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
$xml.manifest.application.label
```